# I couldn't find the way to use "valinit" in the rangeslider widget of matpoltlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rangeslider

I'm trying to use Matplotlib `RangeSlider` and everything is ok except "valinit" value. I just couldn't find how to use it.

> **valinit** : tuple of float or None, default: None
>
> The initial positions of the slider. If None the initial positions will be at the 25th and 75th percentiles of the range.
> https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RangeSlider

I want to make initial position of the slider as 0%-100%, in my case `(0, totaltimest)` not the default 25%-75%, but I couldn't figure it out. Can somebody help me please? An example would be great.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RangeSlider
import soundfile as sf

file='A.wav' # mono audio file


data,fs=sf.read(file)

totaltimest=len(data)/fs

x = np.linspace(0, totaltimest, len(data)) 
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.plot(x,data, label='Reference', color='red',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0.6)
ax.set_facecolor('#EFEFEF')
(yl1,yh1)=ax.get_ylim()
scroll1 = plt.axes([0.22, 0.01, 0.60, 0.03], facecolor='#EFEFEF')
scroll1v = RangeSlider(scroll1, 'Window', 0, totaltimest, valinit=None) # PROBLEM

def update(val):
    pos1=scroll1v.val[0]
    pos2=scroll1v.val[1]
    ax.axis([pos1, pos2,yl1,yh1])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

scroll1v.on_changed(update)

plt.tight_layout
plt.show()
```

Comment: I can't run your example since I don't have the `A.wav` file. Perhaps you could make it a [MCVE]? What have you actually tried for `valinit`? Did you try: `scroll1v = RangeSlider(scroll1, 'Window', 0, totaltimest, valinit=(0, totaltimest))` ? If so, what happened when you did?

Comment: also, I noticed you had a typo of `valint` rather than `valinit` in your title and post, but since you had it spelt correctly in your code block, I assume that wasn't the source of your error

Answer (score 0):

Figured someone else might find this useful so better late than never, but give this a shot:

```
scroll1v = RangeSlider(scroll1, 'Window', valinit=(0,totaltimest))
```

Here's an example of how I used it in conjunction with Numpy arrays for my own project. I was previously working with two separate sliders, but recognizing that the Slider widget works differently than a RangeSlider (float vs. tuple), we have to format the argument for *valinit* as a tuple as well. Check it out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RangeSlider

# Creating axis and slider:
ax_rgb = plt.axes([0.23, 0.18, 0.10, 0.70]) # X-cord, Y-cord, Width, Height
sl_rgb = RangeSlider(ax_rgb,
                     label = 'RGB Array',
                     valinit = (np.max(rgb),np.min(rgb)),
                     valmax = np.max(rgb),
                     valmin = np.min(rgb),
                     orientation = 'vertical')
```

Depending on how comfortable you are with Matplotlib widgets, might not be a bad idea to indent and label your Slider attributes. Cheers!